# My html page not showing my json data

Tags: jquery, html, json, visual-studio

I am new to json and I am using microsoft visual studio to develop a simple web page. I have created the json file and put it into a drive say D://. Now I have to read the json data and show in my webpage when I click the button. whats going wrong.

```
<title>Welcome</title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#hop").click(function(event) {
            $.getJSON('d://final.json', function (jd) {
                $("#hi").html('<p>Name :' + jd.name + '</p>')
                $('#hi').append('<p>Age : ' + jd.age + '</p>');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Get Json Data</h1>
    <div id="hi">
        Hi
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="hop" value="ShowJsonData"/>
</body>
```

final.json:

```
{
    "name": "stack"
    "age":"15"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to open console and see what the error is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot make AJAX requests to the local file system due to the security restrictions of modern browsers.

You need to run your code through a web server, such as IIS or Apache, either on the local machine or remotely.